Documentclass Report: Undefined Control Sequence
What mistake am I making? Am I missing something?
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{report}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}

EDIT:
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
Learn more
l.2 \abx@aux@refcontext
                       {nty/global//global/global} 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 12982 strings out of 475237
 209491 string characters out of 5764570
 1916244 words of memory out of 5000000
 34073 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 560628 words of font info for 39 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 70i,0n,79p,859b,393s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s


No issues here. Please provide the log file from your compilation of this example that gives and error. Or at least cite the entire error.

@daleif see edit

Try first to delete all latex temporary files an recompile from scratch (see also this answer).

You need to delete your aux files. Most editors have a button for this. What you show here is from an earlier doc, what wrote something to the aux file and now you have reused this filename and so the macro in the aux is no longer supported with the new preamble. I have a file where I do my testing of all my answers for this site and I just add the new doc to the top of the file, so I run into this very often.

@jlab thank you. How can I delete the aux files in overleaf? Any experience?

@daleif downloading and uploading the folder solved the problem for me!

@s28 Sorry, I don't use overleaf. I think someone will give you an answer.

There is a dropdown button on the green compile button. As the end of that list it says recompile from stratch, I would assume that clears everything and starts over.

@daleif thanks a lot!
